# Redirect WordPress Dynamic URL to a page URL using nginx

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx, dynamic

I'm trying to redirect a dynamic url to a wordpress page URL. I've tried lots of ways to do it but unfortunately none worked.

The only way it worked, it was to use a `wp_redirect`, but that is very slow in my opinion and I think it does HTTP requests before redirecting to the other URL to do the same HTTP requests all over again.

---

**I'm interested in redirecting the following:**

- `www.domain.com/country-classified-ads/?filter=all&type=cyprus-cars-bikes-vehicles-ads&submit=`

**to this:**

- `www.domain.com/cars-and-vehicles-for-sale-country/`

---

Comment: You could show the nginx configuration you tried.

Comment: Use a plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/ And also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

### I used a WordPress plugin instead of nginx configurations.

Even though I was trying to do this on the server side of my website I found a plugin that does the same work very well.

I used this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) ( Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin ) first but it was slow.

After that, I tried this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) ( Redirection ) and it works awesome, as fast as a server redirect!

> You can use whichever you like. For me, the second one ( Redirection ) worked better/faster.